# How to improve webpack / babel build performance without using the watch feature?

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm working on a SBT/Scala web project and I wanted to take advantage of the ES6 features and the new module syntax for the frontend JavaScript layer. SBT has its own build system and I managed to tweak an existing sbt plugin to run webpack to build my JS files using babel. The current solution is a little messy but it works and lives within the sbt build system.

The problem is that **it's slow**. For every change a new instance of webpack is created and it compiles everything completely from the scratch.

I know I could jump out of the sbt build system and just for the development phase use webpack separately to watch and rebuild my files. But before I do that I was wondering if there are some ways to speed up the webpack build process.

I checked the documentation and it seems to me that any available caching is handled only in memory and that is inapplicable to my case. Or is there some kind of file cache that would survive between separate runs of webpack build? For instance, all of my npm dependencies won't change most of the time so they could be compiled once, cached and then simply included...

Answer (score 38):

Some configuration to consider:

- [module.rules include](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulerules) - You should set `include` to point at your source. By default it will traverse everything (`node_modules` in particular is slow). Make sure you have it set
- [resolve.unsafeCache](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#moduleunsafecache)
- [module.noParse](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#modulenoparse)
- Enable **babel-loader** caching - `loader: 'babel?cacheDirectory'`.
- [aliasing already built, minified libraries](https://christianalfoni.github.io/react-webpack-cookbook/Optimizing-development.html)
- *future* - [cache](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache) - This might work [one day](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/250). Sadly there's no nice way to serialize the cache data yet.

Comment: Could you tell whether we have the similar capabilities for systemjs?

Comment: Do you mean the webpack 2 specific bit? If so, I don't think it will affect the situation a lot.

Comment: We are using systemjs builder (https://github.com/systemjs/builder) instead of webpack. And we also experience performance issues during build process. So I'm wondering whether systemjs builder has something similar to improve performance.

Comment: Ah, you might want to open a separate question about that. :)

Comment: `module.loaders` is not supported since webpack2. It's now [module.rules](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/#moduleloaders-is-now-modulerules)

Comment: @johannchopin Thanks for the heads up! I've updated accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that it's slow. For every change a new instance of webpack is created and it compiles everything completely from the scratch.

We've hit this same issue when our module-base got big (3.5k+) where webpack would take as long as 80 seconds on a regular MacBook 13 to perform the *initial* build.

The approach we took was to parallelize the transformation phase (webpack loaders, basically) which yielded a gain of as much as 500% in terms of build time on some machines. Check out https://github.com/amireh/happypack for the plugin and see if it may work for you.

It doesn't support all the loaders yet, but `babel-loader` is supported which I believe is what you need.

Comment: HappyPack is great - just wish it worked with TypeScript

Comment: HappyPack is really so fast. Before using HappyPack, build time takes me 70s, now it's only 35s.

Comment: @CoolGuy, can you provide a code snippet to how it can be used with `create-react-app` ..

Answer (score 2):

Webpack has a feature that will let you create 'DLLs' (aka. "library bundles") which you can compile, once, separately from your main application code.

A typical workflow with this would be to put any large, infrequently changing libraries in a vendor library bundle which you compile once and then create a much smaller app bundle for your own code.

I wrote up a post on how to do this here: https://robertknight.me.uk/posts/webpack-dll-plugins/

Of @bebraw's suggestions above, I would point in particular to 1) aliasing existing minified libraries instead of including them in the bundle - which achieves the same benefits as creating library bundles and 2) If you are using a transpiler, it is important that the transpiler is only run on your own code via the `module.loaders.(include|exclude)` options, not all of the library code in `node_modules/`

Comment: Thank you for the tips. At the end of the day the problem is that it's not just about the speed, it's also about hot reloading and other cool webpack features that would be hard to replicate in sbt (or am I wrong?). Right now I'm developing using webpack and sbt build system is turned off for JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sbt but getting hot reloading working requires that you run webpack in watch mode at least (you don't have to use webpack-dev-server), so that webpack will generate the `*.hot-update.(js|json)` files that the client uses to check for and apply hot updates.